# How can I go to an html page while passing a hidden parameter using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Upon completion of an ajax call I would like to direct the user to an html page, but at the same time passing a hidden variable (this variable contains sensitive information and should not show up in the URL).

How can I accomplish this?

```
window.location.href = 'userpage.html?id=14253';
```

But with the id remaining invisible? Can I POST the id somehow while sending the user to userpage.html?

Comment: Looks like you are looking for the wrong solution. What kind of information? Who shouldn't see it, the user?

Comment: You can't pass data between pages with JavaScript. You'd need storage or a query string.

Comment: @charlietfl Only problem with storing it as a cookie is that browsers can disable cookies.

Comment: @plalx The information would be an id, I don't want someone to be able to change the id and see information for another user.

Comment: @PaulG You should be checking to see if the ID belongs to an owner before returning a response anyhow.

Comment: Yep. Security should be handled by a server, not client-side scripting.

Comment: @PaulG might consider creating UUID's but If server supports dynamic language implement  user session management and keep the data away from users

Comment: @RhapX That's what the AJAX call does, if the user's password is correct, the user's id should be sent to the next page. But the id is autoincrement, if I swap 110 with 111 in the URL I will see someone else's info.

Comment: @PaulG Authenticating me on one page and passing that data to another page will do nothing without backend security to see if the user who is logged in, has access to the data being requested.  I could hit your second page with just a random number and it would return the result of whatever I request (if it exists) is what you're telling me. Thus, making the login request pointless.

Comment: @RhapX This is why I want the second page to not take the parameter in the URL itself but be hidden

Comment: @PaulG It doesn't matter where the ID is coming from. It could be a cookie, a POST request, the URL, etc. the data is insecure if you are not checking it against some type of backend. Just because it doesn't show up in the URL doesn't mean I can't pass the same data another way to your webpage and get a result without be authenticated.

Comment: @RhapX Understood. What do you suggest I do server side to populate my second page based on who the user is?

Comment: @PaulG I posted a quick answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be checking user credentials on the client side of your website. Regardless of how the ID is being passed to your script, it can be replicated without you being able to check if the request is valid.

To start being even remotely secure with what information is granted to a user, you need to be checking it via the server side. With every request, ensure the user is authenticated to view such data.

If I were you, I would look into using PHP sessions as the first line of defense for checking if a user is authenticated. Doing so will at least keep the information about a user out of a replicable space that can be viewed by the user.

Look up 'php session login tutorial' on Google and you will find plenty of simple tutorials which should get you on the right track.

[Example Tutorial](http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson12.php)

Answer (score 0):

No matter what, the information you pass along is insecure.  You can submit a post request using XMLHttpRequest objects if you'd like (or use a framework/library to make AJAX calls) -- but the user could still spoof the data and get different results.

ID enforcement should be done in the backend.  Does the requested ID match the ID of the user signed in?  No?  Don't show it.  etc etc.

Comment: I'm using AJAX to identify the user based on his username and password. When I've ID'd the user I want to send him/her to another page with the ID associated with them so I can use it to run a query and populate the second page.